# Make foreign key as auto increment in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have these table structure in MySQL, and according to my requirement its working fine.

```
CREATE TABLE `ebasic` ( <br>
`eid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, <br>
`d_id` int(11) NOT NULL, <br>
`pos` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
`hdd` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
`hmm` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
`hyy` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
`fname` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
`lname` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
`bdd` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
`bmm` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
`byy` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
`gender` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
`addr` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
 `city` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
 `state` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
 `pin` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
 `country` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
 `tel` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
 `mobile` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
 `email` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
 `qual` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
 PRIMARY KEY (`eid`) );<br>



CREATE TABLE `eaccount` ( <br>
`eid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, <br>
`d_id` int(11) NOT NULL, <br>
`accno` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
`pan` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
`passport` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
`visa` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
`type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, <br>
KEY `eid` (`eid`), <br>
FOREIGN KEY (`eid`) REFERENCES `ebasic` (`eid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ); <br>
```

So, the column `eid` is primary key in `ebasic` and foreign key in `eaccount`, so that if row is deleted from `ebasic`, it gets deleted from `eaccount` too, because of `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

But, both of them are auto increment columns, too, so when a row is inserted into `ebasic` successfully, the corresponding row with `eid` same as `ebasic` is inserted into `eaccount` with auto increment number same.

Now, I am trying to migrate my database to  SQL Server, what I have there for auto increment is `IDENTITY(seed, increment)`. But, I can't make foreign key as auto_increment here in SQL Server but in MySQL its possible. Please help !!

Comment: You cannot do that in MS SQL, you can try this - first insert a row in ebasic then get inserted row eid and insert that into eaccount table.

Comment: for that i have to refract the whole project code and it will much time to do that....

Comment: This whole design seems like a really horribly bad idea.... what if the auto increments in `ebasic` and `eaccount` suddenly get out of sync?? This is not a very reliable way to go!! You need to insert into  `ebasic` and then fetch whatever `eid` you got, and insert **that** into `eaccount` - anything else is a kludge....

Comment: how do you keep both auto-increments in sync? just 1 insert into 1 of the tables (rather than both) ruins your approach

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server you cannot create foreign keys with auto increment option and set cascading delete option on, if you are inserting a row in one table you can get inserted row id and use that to store in other table that references this key, for example:

```
declare @idtable table (id int);


insert into ebasic (d_id, pos ......)
OUTPUT Inserted.eid INTO @idTable
values (1,2,...);

declare @eid int
select eid = id from @idTable;

insert into eaccount (eid, d_id...)
values (@eid, 1,...);
```